# Active Customers Dataframe from Transactional Data

Tags: python

My goal is to take this transactional data and create an Active Customers *dataframe* formatted just like the example.

```
TransactionID   TransactionDate CustomerID  Amount
1               2012-09-04      1           20.96
2               2012-05-15      2           10.87
3               2014-05-23      2           2.21
4               2014-10-24      2           10.48
5               2012-10-13      2           3.94


ActiveCustomers

Origin                  12  24  36  48  60  72

2010-01-01 – 2010-12-31 172 93  104 91  103 82
2011-01-01 – 2011-12-31 170 92  98  89  88  
2012-01-01 – 2012-12-31 163 109 98  90      
2013-01-01 – 2013-12-31 180 103 102         
2014-01-01 – 2014-12-31 155 90              
2015-01-01 – 2015-12-31 160
```

Comment: Is that exactly how you want the Active Customers table to look? Is all the data under one column? e.g is 12 part of the line '2010-01-01 – 2010-12-31 172 93  104 91  103 82'?

Comment: Yes, 2010-01-01 – 2010-12-31 172 93  104 91  103 82 is one row. And 72 82 is one column.

Comment: I meant how does this line, Origin                  12  24  36  48  60  72.

Comment: Are those column names or are they part of the data? the schema does not look tabular so i'm confused exactly how this is supposed to look?

Comment: Sure, you can find what I'm trying to accomplish here: https://gormanalysis.com/practical-guide-to-calculating-customer-lifetime-value-clv/

Comment: It seems that there is a pre-processing step that you need to undertake that involves sorting customers by date that they first joined. Once you have that as a column, it will be easier for you to aggregate the data into the the ActiveCustomers format.

Comment: I agree, thanks for looking at this for me.

Comment: It doesn't seem like I've helped you in any way in that case. Maybe re-frame your question and make it more specific as to what exactly in your problem you want help with and what you have tried so far?

Comment: I need to reproduce the first column in 'ActiveCustomers' as a date range, specifically one calendar year per row. And I think that I can figure out the counts for each bucket from there (I hope).

Comment: Hey, I'm the author of the post you linked to.  If you're open to using R check out my package: [trinalysis](https://github.com/ben519/trinalysis).